# Simple game for Windows to test a joystick controller

Tags: windows, game

I have built a custom joystick controller as a part of my project. It consists of a single joystick controller (for x/y directions) and 4 buttons.

Which game for Windows 7 can I use to demonstrate my controller?

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a game? I don't think so.

Alias Pointy, Author of Pointy's Blog and [KeyBinder](http://www.planetpointy.co.uk/keybinder/) did run into the same problem while developed the aforementioned application.

The solution? He wrote a tool to test joysticks. Get [Pointy's Joystick Test](http://www.planetpointy.co.uk/joystick-test-application/) from his blog.